# Import Table from Web into Excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping

I am trying to import the following table into an Excel https://bondtradedata.iiroc.ca/#/search (and be able to refresh it).

The table can't seem to be recognized from the Excel "Web import" option and when I try to code it, I get an error.

I don't know if it is because there is an "I am not a robot" test when entering the page, of why the table is not recognized.

If anyone has some input on this, or would be able to help me solve it, would be amazing :)

Comment: "I get an error" is not a good information about what you've tried... can you be more precise?

Comment: Sorry - I can't find the Table in the code source of the webpage and when I try to pull the webpage in VBA it highlights it and wont go further. @NicoHaase

Comment: If you cannot find the table you'd like to import in the source code, how should your program do it? The URL makes me think about data that is loaded through AJAX, so that won't work with your approach

Comment: do you know what would be the best approach for this? @NicoHaase

Comment: Yes, ask the webmaster for a proper API. Scraping is never a good idea